# What is the difference between directly awaiting an async function and calling a async function, saving the result in variable and awaiting a variable

Tags: .net, async-await

```
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var janeTask = getDatafromApiAsync("Jane", 1000);
    await JaneTask;
    
}  


private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    
    await getDatafromApiAsync("Jane", 1000);
   

}
```

In the two snippet above, is there any difference? I'm really confused even after reading few articles.

Comment: Well, one calls getDatafromApiAsync and the other calls DoWorkAsync. One creates a stopwatch and the other doesn't. Aside from that, the two are equivalent.

Comment: sorry, just edited the question.

Comment: There is no difference.